# Android openGL GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv to java

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to convert an Android openGL project over to Java and I am having troubles understanding the internals of

```
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(int location, int count, boolean transpose,  float[] value, int offset)
```

In opengl ES i have two arrays each 128 floats in length

```
float[] jointMatrix;
float[] invBindPoseMatrix;
```

It is then sent to the shader with these calls

```
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(jointMatrixHandle, 8, false,DAE.jointMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(invBindPoseMatrixHandle, 8, false, DAE.invBindPoseMatrix, 0);
```

in the shader it is received as

```
uniform mat4 jointMatrix[8]
uniform mat4 invBindPoseMatrix[8]
```

My question is, Is android sending the entire 128 item float array with that one call , and subdividing automatically into 8  4x4 matrices automatically? with offsets of 16.  0-15-31- etc..?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: **YES**.

You might be overthinking this. There's really no magic to it. In most languages, elements of an array are laid out sequentially in memory. So if you look at the memory layout of an array of 8 4x4 matrices, it's just a sequence of 8 * 4 * 4 = 128 floats. They will be *interpreted* a certain way because of the type the array was declared with. But as far as the memory layout goes, it's exactly the same as an array of 128 floats.

So the `glUniformMatrix4fv()` with a count of 8 provides the content of this memory for the 8 matrices. Since, as explained above, an array of 8 matrices is just a sequence of 128 floats in memory, it consumes 128 floats, and copies them directly to the memory used by the matrix array.

One aspect to be careful about with matrices in OpenGL is that they are stored in column major order. This has to be taken into account in the order of matrix elements in the array you pass to `glUniformMatrix4fv()`.

Comment: Thnx Reto, your awesome. Always helping :)